# Trouble installing python openstacksdk on Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, openstacksdk

I am trying to install the python openstacksdk package via PyCharm (using pip in terminal), but I keep getting the following error message.  I only posted a partial error message, I can add the whole message if needed.  Any thoughts?  I am using a Windows 10 machine.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\szadro200\PycharmProjects\opentstack_ck> pip install openstacksdk
Collecting openstacksdk
  Using cached openstacksdk-0.61.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting jmespath>=0.9.0
  Using cached jmespath-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting jsonpatch!=1.20,>=1.16
  Using cached jsonpatch-1.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting keystoneauth1>=3.18.0
  Using cached keystoneauth1-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (314 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requestsexceptions>=1.2.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.4.1 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (5.1.1)
Collecting munch>=2.1.0
  Using cached munch-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.13 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (6.0)
Collecting cryptography>=2.7
  Using cached cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601>=0.1.11 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (1.0.2)
Collecting netifaces>=0.10.4
  Using cached netifaces-0.11.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: os-service-types>=1.7.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (1.7.0)
Collecting appdirs>=1.3.0
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from openstacksdk) (5.8.1)
Collecting dogpile.cache>=0.6.5
  Using cached dogpile.cache-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.7->openstacksdk) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore>=3.0.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from dogpile.cache>=0.6.5->openstacksdk) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpointer>=1.9 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from jsonpatch!=1.20,>=1.16->openstacksdk) (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.14.2 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.7->openstacksdk) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.14.2->keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.14.2->keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.14.2->keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.14.2->keystoneauth1>=3.18.0->openstacksdk) (2021.10.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'netifaces' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.11.0 -Ic:\users\szadro200\pycharmprojects\opentstack_ck\venv\include -IC:\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Python\Pyth
on39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETF
XSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcnetifaces.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\netifaces.obj
      netifaces.c
      c:\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(200): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
```

Comment: Can you post the commands you ran to obtain this error or the url of the manual you where using as guide? I installed a with no problem using pip.

Comment: within PyCharm on my Windows machine, I opened terminal and ran: pip install openstacksdk.  The install begins Ok, but it errors out.  I am going to try and attach the full error message.  the error message also contains the line where I ran the command

Comment: I was able to add the first half of the error message in the original post, does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve my issue when trying to install openstacksdk in Python either by pip install or PyCharm.

I had to install Microsoft C++ Build Tools via the following url https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use pip when you are using pycharm! Just head over to your code and go to the line where you have typed "import openstacksdk" and click it. A red or yellow bulb icon should appear, click on it, and hit the first option: import openstacksdk. Pycharm would automatically download the library for you!

Comment: that's what I first tried, but no luck.  The first error message is this - 

Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for netifaces

Comment: hmm that is weird.. I am getting the same error too. Looks like it seems to be a problem with the latest version of the library. I believe looking for an older version on the web would and manually installing it from there would help?

Comment: That could be one explanation.

Comment: an older version of the openstacksdk?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/openstacksdk/0.60.0/#files Try downloading it from the web